# UIWebView in Swift: exc_bad_access

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

My Swift app with **UIWebView** crashes with **exc_bad_access** when trying to get current URL. It also crashes only in some cases (often depends on the actions performed by user within that **UIWebView**). Try loading the url provided in code and then tapping cancel. It never crashes though if I don't implement methods from `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.

```
class AuthViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var authWebView: UIWebView

init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    // Custom initialisation
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.authWebView.delegate = self
    var url = NSURL(string:"http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4423823&scope=audio&display=mobile&v=5.21")
    var urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    self.authWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView:UIWebView) {
    NSLog( webView.request!.URL!.absoluteString )
}

}
```

I was also trying to implement this method to check if request object exists before getting the URL but it didn't help.

```
    func webView(webView: UIWebView!,
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!,
    navigationType navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if !self.authWebView.request {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the error:

Some **URL** contains special characters, such as **%@** or **#** which is used for formatting in **NSLog**. If any of those characters is used in the string the first argument for NSLog, than more arguments required for formatting.

E.G.

```
NSLog("http://someurl.com/") // this is fine (no special chars used)

NSLog("http://someurl.com/#somehash?x=%@") // this is not fine (%@ is used in URL, NSLog thinks that I'm formatting the string

var someURLString = "http://someurl.com/#somehash?x=%@"
NSLog("%@", someURLString) // this is fine and the way it has to be done
```

Thanks everyone who took a look at my question!

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I was trying to print the absoluteString in Swift and just printing this NSLog ("URL being loaded is" +  url!); where url is a string. your findings on %@ helped me out.